# Выражение "много людей"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Можно сказать, что выражения "много людей", "сколько людей (тут собралось!)" стилистически уступают аналогичным "много/сколько/столько народу"?

Comment: Неожиданный вопрос. Никогда не задумывался. На первый взгляд- если и уступает, то не сильно. Я написал бы скорее "сколько народу" (ну или "народа" - это уже отдельный разговор), но против "людей" тоже ничего не имею против. Подумаю.

Comment: @behemothus: давайте, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

***Много людей и много народу.*** Эти выражения далеко не всегда заменяют друг друга. Причем речь идет **не о стиле речи, а о разных  семантических оттенках.**

**1) Много людей**

«На улицах много людей, оставайтесь дома». В данном случае **индивидуумов** посчитали с какой-то точностью и дали им **количественную оценку**. Выражение «много народа» здесь не подойдет.

Примеры из книг:

*На первое занятие пришло **много людей.** У него даже нет необходимости иметь вокруг **много людей.** У его работ  всегда стоит **много людей**.*

**2) Много народу**

Это оценка **массы людей как единого целого,** причем в чем-то есть схожесть с неисчисляемыми существительными: *много снега, много воды*.  Интересно, что оценка часто дается относительно **заполненного пространства**.

Примеры из книг:

*В вестибюле, как всегда, было **много народу**. Там было так **много народу**,  что они толком даже не поговорили.У брата было уже **много народу**, смеялись, гремела музыка. Получилось очень красочно и нарядно; было **много народу**, прекрасные отзывы.*

А здесь почему **разные сочетания**? *В это время года в Мехико было особенно **много людей. Много народу** приезжает в Даллас осенью.*

Вероятно, речь идет о массе приезжих как едином целом, а вот проживают в городе они  не группой, а по отдельности.

**Даже в бытовых ситуациях** мы различаем эти сочетания. (1) *Не пойдем в этот магазин, там **много народу***  (всё пространство заполнено людьми). (2) В этой очереди много людей (человек десять, наверное),  давай перейдем  на другую кассу.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 29.05.20

Для подведения итога можно сказать следующее. Количество людей мы оцениваем двумя способами, делая выбор по ситуации: или это **дискретное множество** (много людей), или  это **сплошная масса**, объединенная каким-то образом (много народу).

Что касается **стиля, то он ближе к разговорному**. Дело в том, что существительное  ***народ***  в значении ***люди***  нехарактерно для деловой, официальной или научной речи, где обычно используется это слово с другими значениями.

**НАРОД**,  м. 1. Население той или иной страны. Американский н. Цивилизованные народы Европы. 2. Нация, национальность, народность. Народы Африки. Русский н. Трудолюбивый, талантливый н.  3. только ед. Основная трудовая масса населения страны. Трудовой н. Борьба народа за свои права.  **4. только ед.; род.: -а (-у). Люди.** Огромная толпа народу. В театре было **мало народа**. Весь н. вышел на митинг.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Comment: Спасибо вам за интересный вопрос и внимание к языку. Вы  умеете замечать то, над чем окружающие обычно не задумываются.

Comment: Не за что! Очень приятно)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что на стилистическую предпочтительность того или другого выражения влияет не их собственная сравнительная ценность, а *сочетаемость с контекстом*. "Много народу" обычно акцентирует *количество* и подавляет интерес читателя к тому, какого свойства люди обезличены словом "народ". *Людей* бывает *много* там, где о них есть что сказать.

> Там было много людей, пришедших просто из любопытства или от нечего
>   делать.

В этом предложении людей объединяют общим признаком; "народу" или "люду" грамматичеки можно пристроить, но звучало бы хуже. Ещё сложнее "обнародить"  людей в *абстрактном* контексте, т. е. не связанном с их физическим присутствием: "*есть много людей, думающих так-то*" (такое выражение часто встречается в книгах как прием рассуждения). Да и в случаях присутствия, если подразумеваются особые *качества* многих людей, например, собравшихся на научный симпозиум, они перестают быть *несчетным* множеством (народом, толпой или людом) и невольно видятся собранием личностей, людей не вполне обычных ("*много народу собралось на симпозиум*" не звучит).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! А просто восклицание "Сколько же тут людей!" (на улице) хуже аналогичной с "народом" или нет?

Comment: Если это впечатление от количества, то скорее "народу", а если от мелькающих людей в особенных маскарадных костюмах или от множества знаменитостей, возможно и "людей", хотя спонтанная реакция больше зависит от речевых привычек и "народу" более вероятно услышать, и это менее формальное выражение в такой ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Полностью поддерживаю. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Можно сказать, что выражения "много людей", "сколько людей (тут
>   собралось!)" стилистически уступают аналогичным "много/сколько/столько
>   народу"?

Получается, что скорее наоборот. Но прежде всего - определяется контекстом. 
На мой взгляд в этом значении слово "народ" надо характеризовать не только как собирательное (о чем говорили другие авторы), но и как разговорное, даже разговорно-сниженное.

*Я сразу оговорюсь, что стилистика всегда до некоторой степени вещь субъективная, поэтому в ситуации, когда нет надежных авторитетных источников, можно говорить от своего имени. И вот тут как раз тот самый случай.*

Попытаюсь объясниться на сравнении. На первый взгляд разница между людьми и народом (в этом значении) такая же, как между, например, листьями и листвой. Вокруг этой концепции строятся все уже данные ответы. Согласен. Народ здесь понятие несчетное, нельзя сказать "пять человек народу". И в этом его сходство "с листвой".

Но пойдем дальше. Кроме счетности объекта, есть еще признак "измеримости". Мешок (два, три) листвы - сомнений не вызывает. А что с "народом"? Можно сказать "толпа народу", или иногда - "целая площадь", "полный стадион" проч. Но это не совсем то. "Толпа", понятно, единицей измерения не является, а площадь, стадион или зал становятся таковыми только после присвоения им атрибута целый, полный. Другими словами тут измеряется не столько количество (или объем) народа, сколько сама площадь или стадион.

К чему это приводит? Да к тому, что "народ" становится неким пренебрежительным, сниженным синонимом "коллектива". Типа *"Утром мажу бутерброд - сразу мысль: как там народ?"* (хотя тут еще вопрос, в каком значении использовано, но смысл понятен).

Получается, что "народ" предполагает потерю индивидуальности - опять же отличие с листвой, которая состоит из листьев, имеющих некоторые индивидуальные признаки,  но лишенных индивидуальности как таковой. А люди таковую индивидуальность имеют изначально, но теряют её, становясь народом (повторюсь - в разбираемом значении). То есть, если иное не определяется явным контекстом, "народ" здесь означает "толпа", "людишки", чуть ли не "стадо".

Парадоксальность здесь в том, что людьми (человеком) в какой-то период "благородные" величали прислугу, челядь, тем самым лишая их некоторой степени индивидуальности. Я для себя решаю этот вопрос так, что "люди" - это промежуточная стадия лишения индивидуальности: от "персон" к "народу".

И еще одно. Коллектив (любой!) народом в этом смысле не является. У Sharon верно замечено, что в деловом, тем более - научном, стиле "народ" в этом значении не используется. Но этого мало. Даже в разговорном стиле "народ" совершенно неуместен, если речь идет о какой-то управлямой группе. "Сколько у тебя людей (штыков, сабель)?" Ясно же, что не "народу" - руководитель, военный - тем более, так не скажет. И дело ведь не в счетности. Можно ответить "два полка" (как два мешка листвы").

Вот всё это и наводит на мысль, что именно "Сколько народу!" вне соответствующего, очень узкого контекста, будет стилистической погрешностью. А "Сколько людей!" - никогда.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Интересно, хотя и не со всем сразу готов согласиться. Но у меня нет своего чёткого мнения, поэтому могу формировать его на основе ответов... :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Да я сам с собой поначалу не был согласен. Но я не вижу другого внятного объяснения всей этой ситуации.

Comment: Очень понравился ответ. Я почти полностью согласен с ним, но даже если бы не был согласен, проголосовал бы "за" такой способ выражения своего "имхо".

Comment: @grizzly: странно у Вас "за" в кавычках. Двусмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

В Древней Руси «*людин* — незнатный, простой человек», позднее обрёл множественные определения по роду занятости и статусу в обществе. Люди были «безвытные, ближние, боевые, большие, боярские, вечные, вольные, высокие, владычные, волостные, вытные, вящие, городские, давные, данные, дворные, должные, домашние, доспешные, княжьи, лучшие, лучшие, малые, полные, помещичьи, тяглые, чёрные, численные». Количество людей поддаётся счислению: точному (*125 человек*) и оценочному (*немного больше людей*).

Народ — историческая общность людей. Взятое в первом значении слово является синонимом понятия «нация». В третьем —  разг. ед. ч. то же, что люди, толпа.

> Человек, среди толпы народа застреливший императорского посла,
>   подошел пожать мне руку, поблагодарить за мои стихи. (Н. С. Гумилёв,
>   «Мои читатели», 1921 г.)

Словосочетание «много народу» (современные словари рекомендуют писать слово с окончанием на *-а* и считают словосочетание литературным) употребимо как разговорная форма.

Comment: Ваш ответ на вопрос "нет", не так ли? В этом случае я с Вами согласен. (В цитате Гумилёва явно лишняя вторая запятая; сверьтесь, пожалуйста, с источником.)

Comment: Ответ отрицает аналогичность форм и надобность из сопоставлять.